# running parallel AsyncTask

Tags: android, background, android-asynctask

I have a SplashActivity in my application which do some stuff using AsyncTask when I start my application.

I have also created another AsyncTask which downloads data from the server.  Now after I close my application the AsyncTask is still downloading the data.

But when I again start my application my SplashActivity's AsyncTask does not execute its background (doInBackground function) till my downloader AsyncTask is finished, and my application is hanged.

So my question is it that we cant run two AsyncTask parallel? Both AsyncTask are different and doing their own stuff.
Is there a way to do it.

Comment: Please post the relevant code (Tasks and calling Activity)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You will need to use a `thread pool Executor` to execute `AsyncTask`. Default implementation uses a serial executor running on a single thread

So create a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and then use

AsyncTask's [executeOnExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) instead of just execute method

Comment: Is there some kind of drawback by using this method. I.e. do you have to do some extra work by making the AsyncTask parallel?

Comment: @Gee.E using the default executor is better since there is only one thread instantiated , so if you do not have too many tasks running at the same time, the default executor provides better performance, but if there is one asynctask that takes lots of time, you might need a ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: @nandeesh Roger, I'm using the parallel task to fetch data from a cached database. For complex reasons I need the fetcher-task to run parallel, but since the time it takes is negligible I do not see any performance dips. Regardless, thanks for explaining the issue.

Comment: It must be noted that executeOnExecuter will create Data race so you need to be careful.

Answer (score 47):

There has been a change in AsyncTask from Honeycomb release. Older versions had a Thread pool of 10 threads, so you could run 10 tasks in parallel. But for Honeycomb and up, default is a serial executor, which executes tasks one by one.  But you can pass a `ThreadPoolExecutor` for execution:

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
     //--post GB use serial executor by default --
     task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
   } else {
     //--GB uses ThreadPoolExecutor by default--
     task.execute();
   }
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the last argument `new Void[]{}`; omitting it will suffice.

Comment: Your IDE is wrong; varargs are shortcuts to create arrays, so of course the parameter list can by empty. In fact, providing a new array like you have is actually bad practice; you're needlessly instantiating an object. The GC will need to come around and pause your app for a few milliseconds to clean it up again.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. And the Android documentation couldn't be any clearer on this: "public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR. Added in API level 11 - An Executor that can be used to execute tasks in parallel."

Answer (score 4):

Another option is using [AsyncTaskCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/os/AsyncTaskCompat.html) from support v.4 library.

```
AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object>() {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do your parallel task here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        // and fetch result
    }
});
```

Comment: This class was Deprecate in API level 26 and removed in API level 27