# Attempting to run 2 AsyncTasks in parallel, but they appear to block each other

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm working on an app that sends sensor data and receives connection data via UDP. Originally, the app only sent data, and only used 1 AsyncTask. However, the app is now needs to receive data due to a protocol change, and this needs to be handled on its own thread and trigger UI updates, thus, I've created a new AsyncTask for it

**PROBLEM:**

When run independently, the AsyncTasks execute perfectly. However, when I run them at the same time, one eventually completely blocks the other.

**WHAT IVE TRIED:**

Originally, I was using the standard .execute() to start my AsyncTasks. After reading similar questions, I've implemented the function below instead, hoping to force parallel execution:

```
void startAsyncTask(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    else
        asyncTask.execute();
```

I expected this to work, **however, it did not. The two tasks still block each other**.

What could potentially be causing this? My guesses are potentially a limited pool size, since the two tasks are firing at a very frequent rate (perhaps one task eventually dominates the pool, leaving no free threads), but then again, I'm not entirely sure.

**ADDITIONAL CODE:**
Here is how I set up the timers to execute my asynctasks:

```
             timer = new Timer();
             task = new TimerTask() {       
             @Override
             public void run() {
               handler.post(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {  

                      if (dataClient.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
                            dataClient = new udpClient();
                        }

                        if (dataClient.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
                           if(sensorValues != null) {
                               if(isUdpEnabled)
                                   startAsyncTask(dataClient);
                           }
                        }
                  }
                });
              }
        };

        timer.schedule(task, 0, 25);

        timer2 = new Timer();
        task2 = new TimerTask() {       
             @Override
             public void run() {
               handler2.post(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {  

                      if (broadcastClient.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
                          broadcastClient = new udpBroadcastClient();
                      }

                      if (broadcastClient.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
                          Log.d("broadcast test", "Timer fire");
                          startAsyncTask(broadcastClient); 
                          Log.d("broadcast test", "After execute line reached");
                      }
                  }

               });
              }
        };

        timer2.schedule(task2, 0, 50);
```

Comment: using `executeOnExecutor()` will work. you are on the right path.

Comment: Post the `startAsyncTask()` method.

Comment: AsyncTask run in queue one after another if one allready running second not start executing until first will finish his work, Executor Services http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: The THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR should work. I never get a problem with it. But you may be right about the maximum pool size. If you execute lots of tasks in parallel, it is very likely to them to block each other.

Comment: @HamidShatu : method is posted. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ConstantinCerberus : Do you have a recommendation for how I can work around this limitation?

Comment: @pwee92 AsyncTask has limitation for single thread try Executor Services he support more than one parallel thread  here you have some tutorials and explanation http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

Comment: May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910508/running-parallel-asynctask) will help you to work

Answer (score 0):

The actual work of both threads are both posted to the same handler meaning it will cause them to run one after another. If you put a debugging statement before the handler.post you'll see that they both hit that section and then sequential execution begins. Can't you just use new Thread(){...}.start()?