# While loop in Async task block the execution of another Async task

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have started two services in an activity named StartServiceActivity.

In the On create method of the StartServiceActivity I have started two services, service 1 and service 2.

The services are creates successfully.

1. On the onstart method of **service 1** I have started an asynTask1.

   The asynTask1 executed successfully and entered into the doInBackGround()

   In the doInbackground() of asynctask1(service1) I have created a `while(true){`
2. On start method of service2 I have started an asynTask2.

   Then I trying to start **asynTask2** but it failed to start. The doInBackground() of asynTask2 is not being executed
3. When I comment the `while(true){` in asynTask1 both asynTask1 and asynTask2 is started.

   I want to execute async1 and asyn2 with `while(true)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because `AsyncTasks` run in serial order i.e. one after another. Take a look at [Order of execution](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) here.

So what is happening is: There is a while loop in the `task1` which runs first. The while loop doesn't finish so the `task2` doesn't get turn to be executed.

**Solution:**

You need to set the executor for the `AsyncTask` manually so that the default (serial) executor is not used. Do something like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
     //--post GB use serial executor by default --
     task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
   } else {
     //--GB uses ThreadPoolExecutor by default--
     task.execute();
   }
```

Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910508/running-parallel-asynctask)