# AsyncTasks parallel execution

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a little doubt over the execution of the Async. task i want to minimize the time taken by the http requests that my application is executing,so after some R&D on the internet i opted for the option described below,My question is using the code described below,will my requests will be processing in parallel,if yes is this one the best efficient method,if not how can i make them execute in parallel so that user don't have to wait much!
Best Regards.

```
 if (isInternetAvailable) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {


                new DownloadXmlTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, URLORDERLIST);
                new DownloadXmlTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, URLORDERDETAILS);
                new DownloadXmlTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, URLCUSTOMERDETAILS);

            } else {


                new DownloadXmlTask().execute(URLORDERLIST);
                new DownloadXmlTask().execute(URLORDERDETAILS);
                new DownloadXmlTask().execute(URLCUSTOMERDETAILS);

            }


            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Fetch Data",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(

                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please Try Again Later,No internet Connectivity Detected!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Yes it will execute in parallel, try using `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, mArgs);` and you will see the difference on how slower this is

Comment: possible duplicate of [running parallel AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910508/running-parallel-asynctask)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

1. `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params)` for parallel execution
2. `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, params)` for serial execution
3. `task.execute()` default/generally used option