# What happens with view references in unfinished AsyncTask after orientation change?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-adapter, android-orientation

Note this question was inspired by a comment to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33370816/519334 .

I have a holder class that belongs to a GridView-item with a reference to an ImageView

```
public static class Holder {
    ImageView mRowImage;
    String mImageUrl;

    // neccessary to cancel unfinished download
    BitmapLoaderAsyncTask mDownloader;
}
```

The corresponding GridItemAdapter uses an AsyncTask to get the image for the GridItem

```
public class GridItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, ...) {
        ...
        if (view == null) {
            holder = ...
            ...
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }
        ...
        // cancel unfinished mDownloader
        if (holder.mDownloader != null) {
            holder.mDownloader.cancel(false);
            holder.mDownloader = null;
        }
        holder.mImageUrl = mImageUrls.get(position);
        holder.mDownloader = new BitmapLoaderAsyncTask()
        holder.mDownloader.execute(holder); 
    }
}

static class BitmapLoaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Holder, Void, Bitmap> {
    Holder mHolder;
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Holder... holders) {
        mHolder = holders[0];
        ...
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(...) {
        mHolder.mDownloader = null; 
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            this.mHolder.mRowImage.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
        this.mHolder = null;
    }
}
```

A comment suggested that there might be a problem with this code after orientation change.

Szenario

- Grid is in Landscape - mode
- GridItemAdapter starts BitmapLoaderAsyncTask#1 for loading Image1.jpg

  - async task has mHolder.mRowImage
- Grid orientation changes from Landscape to Portrait mode
- BitmapLoaderAsyncTask#1 finishes and calls `onPostExecute(..)`
- (!!!) In `onPostExecute(..)` the image `mHolder.mRowImage` is updated. Since `mHolder.mRowImage` does not exist any more because orientation change so there should be a crash.

I have [code similar to the described scenario](https://github.com/k3b/AndroFotoFinder/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/androFotoFinder/gallery/cursor/GalleryCursorAdapter.java)
and up to now I havn-t had the (!!!) crash yet.

My Question

- Is this just coincedence that there was no (!!!) crash yet?
- Is there a simple solution to check in `onPostExecute(..)` that `mHolder.mRowImage` is not valid any more?
- Or is there something in Android that protects the `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 1):

> Since mHolder.mRowImage does not exist any more because orientation
>   change so there should be a crash.

That is not correct, all Threads are GC roots, and your `AsyncTask` is holding strong reference to `View` object (it's inside your `Holder` class) and your `View` has strong reference to Activity/Fragment/etc. So your Activity/Fragment/etc won't be properly garbage collected as long as your `AsyncTask` is running. It won't cause any crash (because View do exists) but memory leak will occur and result will be delivered to old Activity/Fragment/etc.

However if you make sure that `AsyncTask` is cancelled properly everything will be ok. But if you want to be 100% sure you should use `WeakReference` to hold you `Holder` class in `BitmapLoaderAsyncTask`

@edit

The way you do task cancelling now is incorrect. After orientation change all the view will be inflated once again (in new Activity/Fragment/etc), thus view.getTag will always result null.

Comment: current  task cancel code was made to cancel image downloads for images that went out of grid-view. After orientation change giditem with holder are recreated. I agree that there could be a memory leak because of these references `GridItemView.tag` -> `Holder.mRowImage` -> `GridItemView`. if i use `WeakReference` in the `Holder` the  `mHolder.mRowImage` might not be valied any more after rotation in `onPostExecute(..)`

Comment: It is true that `mRowImage` won't be valid after rotation, that's why there are better ways to do work in background thread (like Loaders which survives during screen orientation changes and deliver results to proper Activity/Fragment).