# run only 2 AsyncTask in android (multithreading)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, threadpool

I have a application need to run 2 AsyncTask at the same time.
but one AsyncTask is running something takes a long time, another is  sql process.
So I need the following functions.
Is it possible to do like this? what kind of asyncTask should I use? thank you
[image]

Comment: how did u execute the asynctask? post ur code...

Comment: Use `.zip` from `RxJava` for this. You can easily avoid `AsyncTasks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a thread pool Executor to execute Asynctask. The default implementation uses a serial executor running on a single thread, you want parallel.

So create a ThreadPoolExeecutor and then use Asynctask's executeonExecutor instead of execute method.

Nandeesh solved it here:
[running parallel AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910508/running-parallel-asynctask)

Comment: thank you for your advice.
I use the following to solve the problem: