# Sending multiple HTTP requests in parallel - Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ip, httprequest

I am trying to send HTTP GET requests to all IPs in a subnetwork (192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.254) more than 200 requests, so I can find all devices that I need to interact with, depending on the response I get from all IPs in the subnetwork.

Currently using AsyncTask, but can't find the right way. When I make chain AsyncTask, it's taking forever, like 10 sec. for 5 requests. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running parallel AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910508/running-parallel-asynctask)

Comment: See also [running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)

Comment: Both suggestions are for two AsyncTasks, I think I have read everything, maybe AsyncTask isn't the right way idk.

Comment: Hello @Geesha , so what approach you finally took?