# Parallel AsyncTask issue (application doesn't hang in any case)

Tags: java, android

I have two asyncTasks, say A and B. Both are called from different activities. Situations arise when A needs to be called and then my app moves to another activity and B is called. A's duration is greater than B. Now the problem is that when I invoke A and then move to other activity and invoke B, it waits for A to complete and then B is invoked.

Please understand the question and then downvote if you have to. I've searched thoroughly and then finally decided to ask this one.

How do i make these two AsyncTasks independent of each other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running parallel AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910508/running-parallel-asynctask)

Comment: his case specifically mentions 'application hangs', mine doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsyncTask`s post HoneyComb execute on a single thread:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. After
>   HONEYCOMB, it is planned to change this back to a single thread to
>   avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution. If you
>   truly want parallel execution, you can use the
>   executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params...) version of this method with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR; however, see commentary there for warnings on
>   its use.

To execute them in parallel use:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
     task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
else
     task.execute();
```

Comment: also to let others know, do read why AsyncTasks should be taken care of when running in parallel using the THREAD POOL. In my case, none of the asynctasks were programmed to affect each other in any way so the THREAD POOL was a safe implementation.

Answer (score 0):

By default `AsyncTask` uses `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` i.e. if if you starts an `AsyncTask` it will use `sDefaultExecutor` see [AsyncTask#execute()](https://developer.android.com/samples/DisplayingBitmaps/src/com.example.android.displayingbitmaps/util/AsyncTask.html#l531)

```
@MainThread
public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> execute(Params... params) {
    return executeOnExecutor(sDefaultExecutor, params);
}
```

In your case you need to run your thread in parallel thread pool

1. `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params)` for parallel execution
2. `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, params)` for serial execution
3. `task.execute()` default/generally used option

Comment: yes...this explains why the marked answer is my solution. :) Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
});
```

Call your another asynctask in this method.