# Updating more than one fragments concurrently

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm developing a news app in android platform. For the main screen i'm thinking of having a  tile screen like in Windows mobiles and windows 8 operating systems.

In the main screen there are tiles (Fragments) with specific news headlines. (Sports, Buisness, Science ... ).

Fragments are populated with AsyncTasks. My question is They are populated one after another. Even though i have implemented seperate async tasks to do that.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.buisness_frame_layout,new BuisnessFragment());
    transaction.add(R.id.science_frame_layout,new ScienceFragment());
    transaction.add(R.id.sports_frame_layout,new SportFragment());
    transaction.commit();
```

this is written in the onCreate() method of the main screen activity.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buisness, container, false);

    headlineListView=v.findViewById(R.id.lv_main_buisness);
    progressBar=v.findViewById(R.id.pb_buisness_headliines);

    new BuisnessNewsDownload().execute("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=MyAPI");

    return v;
}
```

this is the code of the Fragment with is responsible of populating the buisness news in the fragment.

`new BuisnessewsDownload().execute();` is the async task which downloads and parse the data in order to display it in the fragment.

Data is being downloaded and fragments are getting populated. Though it happens one after another. I want to make them download and populate the data concurrently.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13910508

Comment: This solved my issue.How can i accept this as my answer?