# Cannot execute task: the task is already running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am calling the `AsycnTask` inside the `Adapter`, but when I scrolling the `RecyclerView` some error appears, and this is the error.

```
E/MainAdapter: getAttachment failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
```

and this is my code.

```
class MainAdapter(private dataSet: ArrayList<MyObject>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()
    // some stuff here...

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        disposable.add(
            getApiService().getAttachment()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observerOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                    { it ->
                        Log.i(TAG, "getAttachment success")
                        if (fileType.isImage) {
                            holder.imageLoader.execute(it.byteStream()) // the error is pointing here
                        } else if (fileType.isVideo) {
                            holder.videoLoader.execute(it.byteStream())
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "getAttachment fail", it)
                    }
                )
        )
    }


    class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View), OnMediaLoaderListener {
        override fun onImageLoadFinish(bitmap: Bitmap) {
            Glide.with(itemView)
                    .load(bitmap)
                    .into(itemView.img)
        }

        override fun onVideoLoadFinish(uri: Uri) {
            itemView.video.setVideoURI(uri)
            itemView.video.start()
        }

        val videoLoader = VideoLoader(this)
        val imageLoader = ImageLoader(this)
    }

    class VideoLoader(private val listener: OnMediaLoaderListener): AsyncTask<InputStream, Void, File>() {
        // some stuff here...
    }

    class ImageLoader(private val listener: OnMediaLoaderListener): AsyncTask<InputStream, Void, Bitmap>() {
        // some stuff here...
    }
}

interface OnMediaLoaderListener {
    fun onVideoLoadFinish(uri: Uri)
    fun onImageLoadFinish(bitmap: Bitmap)
}
```

I don't why this error appear.
Any idea on how to properly call the `AsyncTask` inside the `Adapter` and to prevent this error?

Thanks.

Comment: This post will solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910508/running-parallel-asynctask

Comment: @dotGitignore Have u tried the below solution, please let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 0):

An `AsyncTask` can only be executed once. Execute is being called multiple times inside onBindViewHolder in your case.

New instance of AsyncTask is required for every executes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `executeOnExecutor` of the `AsyncTask`.Which are able to execute multiple tasks at once.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
     YOUR_TASK.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
 else
     YOUR_TASK.execute();
```

Have a look on the difference between the two are as follow:-

**.execute()** - This function schedules the task on a queue for a single background thread. Means that if you are calling two AsyncTasks and using `.execute()` method to call them, they will execute in a queue(first then second).

**.executeOnExecutor()** - If you want the parallel execution of both `AsyncTasks`, you can use this method for execution of `AsyncTask`. Means both asyncTasks will execute simultaneously.